# filtering non referenced member nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

An OpenStreetMap xml document is composed (among other things) of a set of "node" elements and a set of "way" elements.

The "node" elements can (optionally) nest "tag" elements.

The "way" elements are composed by an ordered list of "node" elements, referenced by the nested elements "nd", with their attribute "ref" pointing to the attribute "id" at the "node" elements.

Here an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.0.2">
  <node id="1726631203" lat="50.8500083" lon="4.3553223" visible="true" version="6" changeset="9938190" timestamp="2011-11-24T22:05:32Z"/>
  ...
  <way id="160611697" user="toSc" uid="246723" visible="true" version="1" changeset="11385198" timestamp="2012-04-22T14:57:19Z">
    <nd ref="1726631203"/>
    <nd ref="1726631223"/>
    <nd ref="1726631213"/>
    <nd ref="1726631205"/>
    <nd ref="1726631185"/>
    <nd ref="1726631203"/>
  </way>
  ...
</osm>
```

My question is how, using XSLT, could I do the following transformation ?

- Filtering all the node elements that are not referenced by any way element.
- Filtering the way elements that reference node elements not included in the source xml document.
- Changing the attribute "visible" to "false", to any "node" element not having "tag" children elements.

Any other elements should remain in the generated xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how, using XSLT, could I do the following
>   transformation ?
>
> - Filtering all the node elements that are not referenced by any way element.
> - Filtering the way elements that reference node elements not included in the source xml document.
> - Changing the attribute "visible" to "false", to any "node" element not having "tag" children elements.

**This transformation fullfills all three requirements:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kND-By-Ref" match="way/nd" use="@ref"/>
 <xsl:key name="kNodeById" match="node" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node[not(key('kND-By-Ref', @id))]"/>
 <xsl:template match="way[nd[not(key('kNodeById', @ref))]]"/>

 <xsl:template match="node[not(tag)]/@visible">
  <xsl:attribute name="visible">false</xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (suitably created to contain a case for each requirement):

```
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.0.2">
    <node id="1726631203" lat="50.8500083" lon="4.3553223" visible="true"
      version="6" changeset="9938190" timestamp="2011-11-24T22:05:32Z">
      <tag/>
 </node>
    <node id="1726631223" lat="50.8500083" lon="4.3553223" visible="true"
      version="6" changeset="9938190" timestamp="2011-11-24T22:05:32Z"/>
    <node id="ZZZZZZZ" lat="50.8500083" lon="4.3553223" visible="true"
      version="6" changeset="9938190" timestamp="2011-11-24T22:05:32Z"/>
    <way id="160611697" user="toSc" uid="246723" visible="true"
      version="1" changeset="11385198" timestamp="2012-04-22T14:57:19Z">
        <nd ref="1726631203"/>
        <nd ref="1726631223"/>
    </way>
    <way id="160611698" user="toSc" uid="246723" visible="true"
      version="1" changeset="11385198" timestamp="2012-04-22T14:57:19Z">
        <nd ref="1726631203"/>
        <nd ref="1726631223"/>
        <nd ref="1726631213"/>
        <nd ref="1726631205"/>
        <nd ref="1726631185"/>
        <nd ref="1726631203"/>
    </way>
</osm>
```

**the wanted, correct result** (all filterings are performed and the `visible` attribute of one of the `node` elements is turned to `false`) **is produced**:

```
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.0.2">
   <node id="1726631203" lat="50.8500083" lon="4.3553223"
    visible="true" version="6" changeset="9938190" timestamp="2011-11-24T22:05:32Z">
      <tag/>
   </node>
   <node id="1726631223" lat="50.8500083" lon="4.3553223"
    visible="false" version="6" changeset="9938190" timestamp="2011-11-24T22:05:32Z"/>
   <way id="160611697" user="toSc" uid="246723" visible="true"
    version="1" changeset="11385198" timestamp="2012-04-22T14:57:19Z">
      <nd ref="1726631203"/>
      <nd ref="1726631223"/>
   </way>
</osm>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule is overriden by three templates, each implementing one of the three requirements.
2. The two overriding templates that have empty bodies implement the two filtering requirements.
3. We are using keys to conveniently and efficiently find `node` s by their `id` attribute and `nd` s by their `ref` attribute.
4. The attribute value replacement requirement is implemented in the third overriding template.

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer @Dimitre !.
Just trying to understand the logic of this: When declaring the keys, why did you write "way/nd" and "node" in the match condition instead of "/osm/way/nd" and "/osm/node" ?, my problem is that I do not get where is the current context path for the "key" function on this line:

<xsl:template match="node[not(key('kND-By-Ref', @id))]"/>

In other words, it seems to me that the path in the key function should be either absolute (as I wrote above) or in the context of the node element, since that it the element matched by the 'match' condition.

Comment: @Sergio: The expression in the `match` attribute is a "match pattern" and is usually a short, relative XPath expression. Ancestors need to be specified only if disambiguation is necessary. In this case I could have used just `match="nd"` because `nd` elements appear only as children of `way`. If they could be children of 2 differently named parents, then `way/nd` is needed. `match="nd"` means (exactly as with a mtch pattern specified on `xsl:template`: *Match any child of the current node, whose name (of the child) is `"nd"`*.You need to read about match patterns to understand them better.

Comment: I see, and in the last template, why did you write <xsl:template match="node[not(tag)]/@visible"> instead of just <xsl:template match="node[not(tag)]"> ?. It is not the case that in the second case you will also find all the "node" elements without a nested "tag" element ?. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Sergio: I did so, because I want to match the attribute itself -- not the element that holds it, The identity template takes care of the element -- the only node that must be changed is the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//osm/node">
   <xsl:if test="//osm/way/nd[@ref=current()/@id]">

     <xsl:copy-of select=".">

   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

the trick is that the test in the if node returns true if the xpath expression returns one or more results. you can use the same technique to check for the existence of the tag attribute. unfortunately, when you need to alter attributes, you need to copy the other attributes manually (xsl:copy all child elements except the *visible* attribute, instead of simply using of xsl:copy-of).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:if test="//osm/way/nd[@ref=current()/@id]">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="tag">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(local-name(.) = 'visible')]"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="visible">false</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xsl:if test is copied from the previous answer and eliminates the unreferenced nodes.

The bit in the xsl:choose sets the visible attribute to false when tag children are absent. This is a way to change the attribute value *without* having to copy all the attributes individually; but it ignores any child elements other than tag.

I haven't addressed the filtering of way elements.